# Same Python code, same data, different results on different machines

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, anaconda

I have a very strange problem that I get different results on the same code and same data on different machines.

I have a python code based on `numpy/scipy/sklearn` and I use `anaconda` as my base python distribution. Even when I copy the entire project directory (which includes all the data and code) from my main machine to another machine and run it, the results I get are different. Specifically, I'm doing a classification task and I get 3 percent difference in accuracy. I am using the same version of python and anaconda on the two machines. My main machine is ubuntu 16.04 and the results on it are lower than several other machines with various OS on which I tried (OSX, ubuntu 14.04 and Centos). So, there should be something wrong with my current system configuration because all other machines show consistent results. Since the version of my anaconda is consistent among all machines, I have no idea what else could be the problem. Any ideas what else I should check or what could be the source of the problem?

I also removed and reinstalled anaconda from scratch but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you using a train/test split? If so, it could be due to pulling different samples.

Comment: I'm using random seed for that. Also I don't get different results every time I run, I get different results only on one of the machines. So, I guess it must be due to system configuration. But not sure what to check.

Comment: Without a look at the code (and preferably some representative sample data) it's hard to say for sure. The same code/data/libraries ***should*** produce the same result, regardless of OS. Might there be a package version difference where something was changed under the hood between versions?

Comment: @zhespelt The strange thing is that the package versions are also consistent. Just installed anaconda from scratch on my machine and another one and tested. Still get different results.

Comment: Are all the machines the same bit architecture (e.g. 64bit)?

Comment: @Theguy They are all 64bit

Comment: Maybe one version of Numpy is linking with the Math Kernel Library and one isn't?  Just trying to add a data point.

Comment: You could maybe check out numpy [sysinfo](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/distutils/system_info.py) for each of the builds.

Comment: I think it is a long shot but can you delete .pyc files and run again ?

Comment: @Hani deleting pyc files did not help.

Comment: @CodyPiersall I also think that this should somehow relate to underlying math library. However, I printed out info on `mkl` by `sysinfo.get_info('mkl')` on the both machines and they seem identical. Are there any other kernel library that `numpy/scipy` are using?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76500465/1271772

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I found [this discussion](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-distribution-for-python/topic/721634). May be the problem is that MKL(Intel Math Kernel Library) float point operations are non-deterministic by default. So `export MKL_CBWR=AUTO` may solve the problem.

Comment: Hi dim, how can I set the MKL_CBWR?

Comment: It can be set also in linux?

Comment: @LucaMonno, yes you can set on Linux like any other environment variable with `export` or `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 2):

If your code uses linear algebra, check it. Generally, roundoff errors are not deterministic, and if you have badly conditioned matrices, it can be it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on badly conditioned matrices?

Comment: I'd add that when debugging these sorts of issues I would try to do a binary search comparing intermediate results to find the place in the algorithms where things start to differ. Good luck!