# Does fitting Weibull distribution to data using scipy.stats perform poor?

Tags: python-3.x, distribution, weibull, scipy.stats

I am working on fitting Weibull distribution on some integer data and estimating relevant shape, scale, location parameters. However, I noticed poor performance of **scipy.stats** library while doing so.

So, I took a different direction and checked the fit performance by using the code below. I first create 100 numbers using Weibull distribution with parameters shape=3, scale=200, location=1. Subsequently, I estimate the best distribution fit using **fitter** library.

```
from fitter import Fitter
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import weibull_min

# generate numbers
x = weibull_min.rvs(3, scale=200, loc=1, size=100)

# make them integers
data = np.asarray(x, dtype=int)

# fit one of the four distributions
f = Fitter(data, distributions=["gamma", "rayleigh", "uniform", "weibull_min"])
f.fit()

f.summary()
```

I expect the best fit to be Weibull distribution. I have tried re-running this test. Sometimes Weibull fit is a good estimate. However, most of the time Weibull fit is reported as the worst result. In this case, the estimated parameters are = (0.13836651040093312, 66.99999999999999, 1.3200752378443505). I assume these parameters correspond to shape, scale, location in order. Below is the summary of the fit procedure.

```
$ f.summary()
             sumsquare_error          aic          bic  kl_div
gamma               0.001601  1182.739756 -1090.410631     inf
rayleigh            0.001819  1154.204133 -1082.276256     inf
uniform             0.002241  1113.815217 -1061.400668     inf
weibull_min         0.004992  1558.203041  -976.698452     inf
```

Additionally, the following plot is produced.
[image: Plot]

Also, Rayleigh distribution is a special case of Weibull with shape parameter = 2. So, I expect the resulting Weibull fit to be at least as good as Rayleigh.

**Update**

I ran the tests above on Linux/Ubuntu 20.04 machine with numpy version 1.19.2 and scipy version 1.5.2. The code above seems to run as expected and return proper results for Weibull distribution on a Mac machine.

I have also tested fitting a Weibull distribution on data **x** generated above on the Linux machine by using an R library **fitdistrplus** as:

```
fit.weib <- fitdist(x, "weibull")
```

and observed that the estimated shape and scale values are found to be very close to the initially given values. The best guess so far is that the problem is due to some Python-Ubuntu bug/incompatibility.

I can be considered as a newbie in this area. So, I am wondering, am I doing something wrong here? Or is this result somehow expected? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library `fitter` doesn't allow to specify parameters for distributions such as a, loc, etc. And strangely, Mac produces better fit while Linux heavily pains the results for best fit, for the same version of Numpy and Scipy. Underlying reasons may include different BLAS-LAPACK algorithms designed for Linux and Mac, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49274049/6806531, or weibull_min may not initialize parameter `a` = 1 which is discussed online, or default floating-point accuracy. However, one can solve the error inside `fitter` library. Knowing the fact that weib_min is expon_weib with parameter a is fixed as 1, changing the run function inside of _timed_run function in fitter.py as

> ```
>         def run(self):
> ```

```
            try:
                if distribution == "exponweib":
                    self.result = func(args,floc=0,fa = 1, **kwargs)
                else:
                    self.result = func(args, floc=0, **kwargs)
            except Exception as err:
                self.exc_info = sys.exc_info()
```

and using exponweib as weib_min gives nearly same results as R `fitdist`.

Comment: Thank you. In the if-else block you have pointed out, by using either:
                    if distribution == "exponweib":
                        self.result = func(args,floc=0,fa = 1, **kwargs)
or
                    if distribution == "weibull_min":
                        self.result = func(args, floc=0, **kwargs)
I get the expected estimated parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Fitter library, but in order to draw some conclusions I would suggest:

1. Retry your code, but by taking size=10,000. In this case, there are sufficient datapoints for the fitting methods to utilize. Theoretically, you would then expect the Weibull to deliver the best fit.
2. I noticed that the location parameter can sometimes be a pain. You could try to run your fits by fixing the location parameter with floc=1 (i.e. equal to your sampling parameter for location). What do you get? Aditionally, FYI, with MLE, it suffices to take loc=min(x), where x is your dataset. For the exponential distribution, this in fact the MLE of the location parameter. For other distributions I am not sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if this holds for other distributions as well. This would reduce the fitting procedure with 1 parameter.
3. Lastly, I noticed that if you take small values for location/scale/shape for some distributions, the functions logpdf and logcdf of scipy.stats distributions result in np.inf values. In this scenario, you could perhaps use the Powell optimization algorithm and set bounds on the values of your parameters.