# Same python code, same machine, same data, but different results based on state of machine

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python code that reads in two columns of data from a text file and performs a curve fitting procedure. The code is based on numpy amd math libraries, and the first time I ran the code, I got one set of results. During this run, the machine was also running another Python code to do a different analysis. When I reran the code, I observed that I got vastly different results.

To confirm the correctness of these results, I reran the calculation in MATLAB, and was able to reproduce the results obtained from the second run of the Python code. Any pointers on why this is happening would be appreciated. I can share the data and the code privately, if someone needs to test it.

```
import  pandas  as  pd
import  numpy   as  np
import  typing  as  tp
import  math    as  mt
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def curveFitting(energyData: tp.Dict[float, float], order: int) -> None:
    pesDataFrame    =   pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Distance", "Energy"])
    for key in energyData:
        pesDataFrame.loc[len(pesDataFrame)] = [key, energyData[key]]    #   Create a DataFrame to drop all energy values above 0 cm-1
    pesDataFrame    =   pesDataFrame[pesDataFrame["Energy"] <= 0]        #   Drop all energies greater than 0 cm-1
#    pesDataFrame    =   pesDataFrame[pesDataFrame["Distance"] > 1.4]
    distances       =   pesDataFrame["Distance"].to_numpy()
    energies        =   pesDataFrame["Energy"].to_numpy()
    rEquilibrium    =   distances[energies.argmin()]
    
    distances       =   np.delete(distances, energies.argmin())
    energies        =   np.delete(energies, energies.argmin())
    xRvalues        =   np.zeros(distances.size)
    print(rEquilibrium)

    for index, value in enumerate(distances):
        xRvalues[index] =   (pow(value, 3) - pow(rEquilibrium, 3)) / (pow(value, 3) + pow(rEquilibrium, 3)) # Calculate x(r) values according to Eq 14

    xMatrix         =   np.zeros((distances.size, order+1))
    for row, value in enumerate(xRvalues):
        for ordercount in range(0, order+1):
            xMatrix[row][ordercount] = pow(value, ordercount)           #   Calculate xMatrix according to Eq 19
    print(xMatrix.shape)
    
#    term1           =   np.zeros(distances.size)
    term2           =   np.zeros(distances.size)
    rescaledEnergy  =   np.zeros(distances.size)
    minEnergy       =   energies[energies.argmin()]
    dissocEnergy    =   0 - minEnergy               #   Calculate dissociation energy as difference between minimum and zero energy.
    for index, value in enumerate(energies):
        rescaledEnergy[index]   =   (value - minEnergy) / dissocEnergy
   
    for index, value in enumerate(distances):
#        term1[index]            =   np.emath.log(1 - mt.sqrt(rescaledEnergy[index]))    #   Eq 11
        term2[index]            =   np.emath.log(1 - mt.sqrt(rescaledEnergy[index]))    #   Eq 12
        
#        term1[index]            =   term1[index] / (rEquilibrium - value)
        term2[index]            =   term2[index] / (rEquilibrium - value)

    # First calculate beta from Eq 11
    beta, _, _, _   =   np.linalg.lstsq(xMatrix, term2, rcond = None)
    print(beta.shape)

    calculateBetas  =   np.dot(xMatrix, beta)
    errorVector     =   term2 - calculateBetas
    print(np.linalg.norm(errorVector))
#    calculateBetas      =   np.zeros(distances.shape)
#    for row in range(xMatrix.shape[0]):
#        calculateBetas[row] =   np.dot(xMatrix[row], beta)

    calculateEnergies1  =   np.zeros(distances.shape)
#    errorVector         =   np.zeros(distances.shape)

    for index, value in enumerate(distances):
        distance    =   value - rEquilibrium
        betaterm    =   mt.exp(-1*calculateBetas[index]*distance)
        nextterm    =   pow(1-betaterm, 2) * dissocEnergy
        calculateEnergies1[index]   =   nextterm + minEnergy
#        errorVector[index]          =   energies[index] - calculateEnergies1[index]
    error   =   np.linalg.norm(errorVector)
    plt.plot(distances, energies, "-r", label = "UCCSD(T) Energy")
    plt.plot(distances, calculateEnergies1, "-b", label = "Fitted Energies")
    plt.title("Fitting Order : {} and Error : {:10.5f}".format(order, error))
    plt.xlabel("Interatomic Distance")
    plt.ylabel("Energy (cm-1)")
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig("uccsdt_fitting_order_{}.png".format(order), dpi = 600)

with open("energies_neutral_631g.dat") as energyFile:
    uhfEnergy       =   {}
    uccsdEnergy     =   {}
    uccsdtEnergy    =   {}

    for line in energyFile:
        line    =   line.split()
        dist    =   float(line[0])  #   Distance
        uhf     =   float(line[1])  #   UHF Energy
        uccsd   =   float(line[2])  #   UCCSD Energy
        uccsdt  =   float(line[3])  #   UCCSD Energy with UCCSD(T) corrections
        uhfEnergy[dist]     =   uhf
        uccsdEnergy[dist]   =   uccsd
        uccsdtEnergy[dist]  =   uccsdt

for order in range(0,20):
    curveFitting(energyData = uccsdtEnergy, order = order)
    plt.clf()
```

The original data used for the fit is provided [here](https://gist.github.com/HemanthHaridas/df37099b5bb3155c6e45913d4e05a2a9)

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: @Programmer-RZ I have posted the complete code used. However, I cannot post the data publicly.

Comment: Can you create some fake random data that has the same dynamics

Comment: @Carbon I will try both of your suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you show everyone how different your final results were? This would make it more clear to everyone that the answer is not about float32 vs float64. Also @LucaAnzalone, you talk about two different machines, but the question says that both calculations were done on the same machine.

Comment: @Nike Sorry, I misread. I'll remove my comment about the data type.

Comment: I run your code multiple times in a Jupyter notebook, even by changing the random seed, but I always get *exactly* the same results: I got an error of 17.26367 at order 19. If so, I don't see any issue also because there are only deterministic operations in your snippet.

Comment: That's exactly what I also don't understand. I tried the same code in MATLAB and got an error of 17.5xx at order 19, which is comparable to the python result obtained from the rerun.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas can you reproduce the result of the first run?